# POWERBUILDER 11.1 Database Profile Does Contain SNC SQL Native client

Tags: sql, profile, powerbuilder

I have POWERBUILDER 11.1 installed on my workstation, however I dont see the SNC SQL Native client in the Database Profile window.  I have reinstalled the IDE multiple times without succesfuly having the SNC SQL Native Client dipslaying.  My OS is Windows XP 32 bit.

How do I resolve this issue so I can connect to my SQL DB?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the SQL Server Native Client runtime installed on your machine? It's a package from Microsoft that is needed to access SQL Server. You can get the SQL Server 2008 version here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=16978 (Scroll down until you find sqlncli.msi). It needs to be installed on all the client machines that will be accessing SQL Server.

Comment: I've also got a blog post about PowerBuilder and SQL Server here: http://slapouttech.blogspot.com/2012/04/powerbuilder-and-sql-server-tips-on.html

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to do a Full install or a Custom install and select SNC. I don't recall if SNC is part of the default installation, but it sounds like not.

Good luck,

Terry.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can not connect to SQL Server 2008 using PB 11.1, but I am not sure. Maybe you can but I can't remember if it is possible to use all the new features of 2008 version.
I am sure that you can connect to SQL Server 2005 cause I'm doing it every day, but you must first install SQL SNC driver as slapout answered.